# No Variables in Relay generated mutation query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I'm pretty new to Relay so perhaps it's a very stupid error.

I'm trying to make a simple mutation that add a `defect` to a `photo`.

Here is my Relay.Mutation object :

**AddDefectMutation.js**

```
export default class AddDefectMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

    getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation { addDefect }`;
    }

    getVariables() {
        return{
            photoId: this.props.photoId,
            title: this.props.title
        }
    }

    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on AddDefectMutationPayload {
                updatedPhoto {
                    issues
                }
            }
        `
    }

    getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type : 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
            fieldIDs : {
                updatedPhoto : this.props.photoId
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

And here is the part of the GraphQl schema

```
const AddDefectMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
    name: 'AddDefectMutation',
    description: 'Add a new defect and return all the defects.',
    inputFields: {
        photoId: {
            description: 'Photo of this defect',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        },
        title: {
            description: 'A short description of the defect',
            type: GraphQLString
        }
    },
    outputFields: {
        updatedPhoto: {
            type: PhotoGraphQLType,
            resolve: ({localIdIssue}) => driver.getIssuePhoto(localIdIssue)
        }
    },
    mutateAndGetPayload: ({photoId, title}) =>
        driver.addIssue(photoId, title).then(localIdIssue => ({localIdIssue}))
})

const MutationGraphQLType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: () => ({
        addDefect: AddDefectMutation
    })
})
```

My problem is that when I make this call :

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new AddDefectMutation(
        {photoId: this.props.pictureId, title: this.props.title}), {
        onSuccess: ()=> console.log("Mutation Success !"),
        onFailure: transaction => console.error(transaction.getError() || new Error('Mutation failed.'))
    })
```

Relay generate the good mutation query without problem but it doesn't place the variables given in the constructor.

---

EDIT : Here the fragment of mutation generated by relay

```
mutation AddDefect($input_0:AddDefectMutationInput!) {
    addDefect(input:$input_0) {
        ...F4,
        clientMutationId
    }
}
```

And the problem is that `$input_0` is an empty object

Answer (score 1):

The variable `title` is not passed properly to the mutation constructor. In your `Relay.Store.commitUpdate` function call, change `{photoId: this.props.pictureId, this.props.title})` to

```
{photoId: this.props.pictureId, title: this.props.title})
```

Comment: Yes sorry it's à copy aste mistake.

Comment: No it is not in the original code. I have simplifiés this one to avoird unrelevant code

Comment: Not in a position to test myself. Can you try passing the photo itself as a prop to the mutation constructor instead of the photo ID? You need minor changes in `getConfigs`, `getVariables` functions and the `commitUpdate` function call.

Comment: Ok i will post the result

Comment: The code looks good to me. You may want to put a debug log just before calling `commitUpdate` to check if valid `this.props.pictureId` and `this.props.title` values are being passed to the mutation.

Comment: Yes it's also good when the `getVariables` function is called.

Comment: Hummmmm After more research, i think that this comportement is normal... I don't know how the data are passed to the server but it seems that it is passed. My problème certainly come from my neo4j request made on the server side

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. I can see in the console output that everything is setup properly, but in my case `$input_0` is not empty, yet nothing happens on the server side.